# How to add archive file to release using github actions?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to add an artifact file, and DEPLOY.md file from a sub directory to a release when triggered by pushing tag on github actions.
Here is my code for the work flow

```
---
name: Module Three Task Three
on:
   push:
   schedule:
      - cron: '0 0 * * *'
jobs:
   Explore-GitHub-Actions:
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest
      steps:
         - name: Checkout
           uses: actions/checkout@v2
         - name: Clone
           run: |
              git clone https://github.com/mittsahl/validation
         - name: Hugo
           run: |
              brew install hugo
         - name: Create package
           run: |
              cd validation/module3_task3
              make build
              make package
         - name: Archive artifacts
           uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
           with:
             path: |
               validation/module3_task3/awesome-website.zip
         - name: Release
           uses: softprops/action-gh-release@v1
           if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
           with:
            files: |
              DEPLOY.md
              awesome-website.zip
```

The zip file awesome-website.zip and DEPLOY.md are in the directory validation/module3_task3/.
I can create the release on the push of a tag and the archive of awesome-website.zip, but it just gives me a zip file of the entire repo in the release.  What I want is only the DEPLOY.md and artifact or awesome-website.zip file.  When I look in the github actions it gives me the message

```
Run softprops/action-gh-release@v1
 Pattern 'DEPLOY.md' does not match any files.
 Pattern 'awesome-website.zip' does not match any files.
‍ Creating new GitHub release for tag 1.0.0...
 Release ready at https://github.com/mittsahl/validation/releases/tag/1.0.0
 DEPLOY.md,awesome-website.zip not include valid file.
```

I have tried giving it the full path to those files each without any success.  Any input would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you